# Unity offset cycle always starts from beginning?

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

Alright, I am trying to start my animation clip from my animation controller in Unity in C# from a different position in the clip (an offset) every time it is triggered, but Im not understanding how cycle offset works (clearly) and my clip aways seems to start from the beginning regardless.

What I have is a walk cycle that is set off by a bool depending on if character is moving, but Im trying to have the character alternate (have it play the full walk cycle but through the increments of the animation that is played since it is played only when character is moving) their left and right steps. Otherwise it looks weird

How Ive tried to do this is have a float and increase that float ever time they move, and assign that float to the cycle offset of my animation. That way I figure the next time the animation is triggered it will start where it left off.

I am unsure if offset refers to time, frames, or percentage, so I've just done this so far:

```
if (animOffset >= 1f) { //was full clip
            animOffset = 0.0f;
        }

        //anim help
        currentPos = transform.position;

        if (currentPos != lastPos) {
            //print ("moving now");
            animator.SetBool ("isWalking", true);
            if (InputManager.stepCount % 2 != 0) {
                print ("moving right");
                animator.SetFloat ("walkOffset",animOffset);

            } else {
                print ("moving left");
                animator.SetFloat ("walkOffset",animOffset);

            }
            animOffset += 0.1f;
        } else {
            animator.SetBool ("isWalking", false);
        }
        lastPos = currentPos;
```

Problem is Im not getting the desired effect and looking at the animation controller it seems the clip ALWAYS goes from the beginning, see:

[image]

The little blue bar always starts from beginning. What am I doing wrong here? How can I make an accurate run cycle offset?

Comment: 'I am unsure if offset refers to time, frames, or percentage' it refers to percentage (0..1.0)

Answer (score 1):

You can link the "Cycle Offset" on the *animation* to a parameter on the Animator (in this case I've called `Offset`). You can then set this parameter in code:

Here's the animator window (ignore Speed, it's not needed here). I have one state `OnState`.

[image: The animator window showing the onstate]

Here's the inspector window for the `OnState` state. I've ticked `Parameter` next to Cycle Offset and then it let me choose my parameter `Offset`.

[image: The inspector window for the OnState state]

In this code I get the animator and set the property `Offset`, which in turn can be set either programmaticly or through the inspector.

```
public class MyObject : MonoBehaviour
{
  public float Offset= 0f;
  Animator animator;

  void Awake()
  {
    animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    animator.SetFloat("Offset", Offset);
  }
```

Offset is a value [between 0 and 1](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animations.AnimatorState-cycleOffset.html), so you would find where in your animation where your feed move and set that as a proportion of 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else still has this issue as I did:

AnimationClip loop time needs to be checked to use cycle offset, otherwise cycle offset won't have any effect. Valid range is 0 to 1.0.

Make sure loop time is ticked on you animation clip, that fixed it for me. Otherwise, cycle offset did not affect the animation at all.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

This might be what you are looking for [AnimationState.normalizedTime](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationState-normalizedTime.html) to control the position of an animation.